# Load Image in <img> tag using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I know it's a basic question but I could not the reason why it's not showing. I am trying to show a image in a  src tag loaded from php mysql database. What I did -

```
       <ul>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM advertisement_table";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);


            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                 echo    '<li>
                    <img src="'.$row["image"].'" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        <h3>'.$row["title"].'</h3>
                        <p>'.$row["description"].'</p>
                      </li>';
            }
        ?>
      </ul>
```

This is the page link - [link](http://www.freebumba27.com/7dood/website/dashBoard.php)

Comment: well i was confused at first .. then i disabled ad blocker on my browser :-)

Comment: @Dagon Hell yeah, I checked my console log and its showing the error ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT usually shown when adblocker blocks them.

Comment: curious, i get nothing in console for blocked ads (firefox - firebug)

Comment: i dont have an adblocker on chrome - so any way interesting.

Comment: Yes right it's a issue of Ads Blocker. I spent 1 hours. THANKS EVERY ONE>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path contains "ads_images" which is usually blocked by ad-blocker. To resolve this issue, either **rename the folder to anything which is not related to ads** or **disable ad-blocker**.

Comment: May I know the reason why downvote?

Comment: I try to upvote one but still -1 that much I can do thanks @Manikiran